# Wok Seasoning Fail(?)

Tags: seasoning-pans

I was recently trying to season my wok. I cleaned it, dried it, applied a thin layer of oil and put it in the oven for 1hr at 400°F.
I dont know what I did wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think what happened here, and I've seen this with a few woks - is too much oil. You can see the pooling issues at the bottom where likely you've got some flakes that might come off. 
The seasoning process is best not rushed, and when you apply the oil - if you can detect more than a subtle sheen - that's too much oil. It may take a few attempts to get a good seasoning but using more oil is not the solution. I'd give this a good scrub with maybe some steel wool or a scouring pad and try again but with much less oil. You can also rub the pot (carefully) with a paper towel while it's heating to ensure the very thin coating of oil stays somewhat uniform.
Woks, due to their shape tend to get some oil pooling and if you're wiping down while it comes to temp and polymerization occurs then you should get less pooling.

Editing - Adding from comments, heating the wok upside down is a great idea. To be honest I often do this on the stovetop, inverting the wok over a red hot element - ymmv.

Comment: Thank you! The funny thing is it wasnt even sticky

Comment: If you put the wok in the oven upside-down, you avoid pooling issues.

Comment: Yeah, "too much oil" was my first thought too.

Comment: DO NOT USE STEEL WOOL!!!  Please edit this part of your answer.  Steel wool will scratch the heck out of the wok, and it will be destroyed.